# Parse Php Push Notification returns true. How to prevent it from returning a response

Tags: php, parse-platform, push-notification

Ive set up Parse Push Notification successfully on Android and iOS. I am using PHP to send push notifications to devices based on their user ids. The push notifications are being delivered successfully. However on running the PHP code, parse seems to return a response of true. Is there any way to prevent it from 'echoing' a response.

PHP CODE -

```
<?php

$APPLICATION_ID = "XXXX";
$REST_API_KEY = "XXXX";

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';
$data = array(
    'where' => array(
    'user_id' => array('$in' => array('80','19','20','21'))
    ),
    'data' => array(
        'alert' => 'greetings programs',
    ),
);
$_data = json_encode($data);
$headers = array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($curl);

?>
```

RESPONSE:

{"result":true}

Is there any way to prevent it echoing the response - {"result":true}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use - curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete PHP Rest API CURL code for ref:

```
<?php

$APPLICATION_ID = "xxxx";
$REST_API_KEY = "xxxx";

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/push';

$data = array(
    'where' => array(
        'objectId' => array('$in' => array('xx'))
    ),
    'data' => array(
        'alert' => 'test parse message via php script',
    ),
);

$_data = json_encode($data);

$headers = array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: ' . $APPLICATION_ID,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ' . $REST_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($_data),
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result;
print_r($result);
die('finished!');
?>
```

**Note:** It works on my server GoDaddy only, not on localhost - don't know why. May be godaddy version is higher than 5.4.x